# Alternative select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I'm trying to make the a selectable list like a select-box, so when you click on the `li` a, change the label for the selected `li` a.

First of all, this is possible? 
Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dcalixto/h8esW/10/

Thank's for any hint :)

Comment: You could check this plugin and see if it meets your requirements: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable & demo at http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html (Click on the bolded text `Dolor sit` under `Inlined select`

Comment: what this plugin have to do with this?

Comment: Nothing! I thought that would help. Now I am sorry I posted it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible using the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

```
$(".genero-box li").click(function() {
    $genero = $('.genero');  /* Get the <label> */
    $genero.text($(this).text()); /* Set <label>'s text to clicked <li>'s text */
    $genero.click(); /* Trigger a click on the label to close the selection */
});
```

Here's [an update](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Huv/1/) to your code.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you're looking for:

```
$(".genero-box li").click(function(e) {
    $("label.genero").text($(this).text());
    $(".genero-box").fadeOut();
});
```

Check kthis jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/tyHSx/1/